# header filtering using python

Tags: python, python-2.5

i want to filter some headers in a wireshark  capture (converted to text format) so i can analyse these set of headers.i need a python script to do this. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [dpkt](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/).  It's a Python library to simplify reading (or generating) network data.  Just save your Wireshark data as a Pcap stream and it can easily be opened from within Python.

I don't know exactly which headers you want or how you need them filtered and formatted, but here's an example of what you could write: (taken from [a contributor's blog post](http://jon.oberheide.org/blog/2008/10/15/dpkt-tutorial-2-parsing-a-pcap-file/))

```
import dpkt
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(open('test.pcap'))
for timestamp, buf in pcap:
    eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
    ip = eth.data
    tcp = ip.data
    print 'Got data from port ' + str(tcp.port)
```

Comment: i saved the test.cap file in the directory of python26 but eacht ime i run this script it keeps telling me there is no directory file named "test.pcap". is there a particular way that i have to save the pcap stream?

Comment: Well, you said it yourself:  you saved to "test.cap" and you're trying to open "test.pcap" (note the extra 'p').